# How to create unique index in mongodb if the field value has dots(.)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoimport

If a field value is plain text, I could create unique index on a field but If I create unique index on a field value that has dots(.), I am getting errors on adding new document to the collection with unique field value.

Would you please help me to create index to ensure uniqueness based on eq.fdn field?

It is working if there is no dots in the value, but it is not working for eq.fdn field which has special characters..:

I tried below:

**db.test.createIndex({"eq.fdn":"text"},{unique:true});**

(or)

**db.test.createIndex({"eq.fdn":1},{unique:true});**

Below is one of the documents in **test** collection:

```
{
    "fdtn.description": "Power Supply Bay",
    "fdtn.name": "Power Supply Bay 1",
    "eq.connectors": "",
    "eq.containing-equipment": "MD=CISCO_EPNM!ND=39.1.129.58!EQ=name=Chassis;partnumber=ASR-903",
    "eq.ent-physical-index": 30,
    "eq.equipment-type": "OTHER",
    "eq.fdn": "MD=CISCO_EPNM!ND=39.1.129.58!EQ=name=Power Supply Bay 1;partnumber=cevContainerASR900PowerSupplyBay",
    "eq.is-field-replaceable-unit": "FALSE",
    "eq.is-physically-present": true,
    "eq.is-reporting-alarms-allowed": "UNKNOWN",
    "eq.operational-state-code": "up",
    "eq.service-state": "UNKNOWN",
    "eq.vendor-equipment-type": "cevContainerASR900PowerSupplyBay"
}
```

I could create index on eq.fdn field but at the time of inserting a new recording I am getting below error:

```
Error: Error when saving document: 1 E11000 duplicate key error collection: local.test_entry index: test_id_index dup key: { : "1", : 0.85 }
```

I am sure...giving only unique eq.fdn field value.

Comment: why you say "it is not working" ?   - what does it mean? The db goes slow when searching for the index? does it give an error on creation?

Comment: I could create index on eq.fdn field but at the time of inserting  a new recording I am getting error:

Error:
Error when saving document: 1 E11000 duplicate key error collection: local.test_entry index: test_id_index dup key: { : "1", : 0.85 }

I am sure...giving only unique eq.fdn field value.

Comment: and are you sure you really don´t have unique values? how big is your collection? maybe you can create a non unique index on that field, and search for objects in the collection having the same value on eq.fdn or print all values in a text file and check it in just a while wit awk

Comment: I mean - "how did u ensure this?"

Comment: yes I am passing unique values.and I am trying to insert only one record to test the insertion.

Comment: then, it´s failing, for example, when having only 2 different records anyway, you mean this? (you REALLY dont need to check they are different programatically because you know it)

Comment: I am doubting on the way I created index on eq.fdn field using db.test.createIndex({"eq.fdn":"text"},{unique:true});.
is it correct?

Comment: I started checking this at first on mongo docs, let me check again

Comment: thanks in advance alejandro.

Comment: db.test.createIndex( { "eq.fdn": 1 }, { unique: true } )
this is the way

Comment: try it, i´ll write the solution if it works and will explain 2 u

Comment: um.. I read again your question and saw you tried too this?

Comment: I mean: the text indexes are for querying the text. The unique indexes, just are run with a type or 1 or -1 it means asc or desc, and the type is defined according to the type of the field